# PHP: How to use variable first and initialize it later in PHP (using Jquery or Ajax )?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, ajax

I am writing html in PHP file, I am trying to output **$count** value in html but using **for each loop later**, How can i do it,

Code -

```
<div>Total class: <span>$count</span>
<div>Total student: <span>237</span>


<?php
foreach($cursor as $row){
$count = 0;
    foreach($row->class as $item){
                                                   
      $count+= count($row->class);

   }
 }
?>
```

Comment: Why can't you put the PHP code block above the html? Maybe the question needs an update to better explain the issue.

Comment: @AlexBarker bcause i have two loops running It will retuns value many times.

Comment: I have some values that need to print before and after $class that why i am asking

Comment: It's impossible without refactoring your code to do the calculation before the output. Or inventing a time machine...

Comment: _“bcause i have two loops running”_ - how does that answer the question, why you can’t do this before the HTML then? It _doesn’t_. You need to give us _proper_ explanations of your problems. Are you creating output inside of those loops? Well then instead of writing that out directly, you could collect it in a string variable first. Then you output the HTML you have shown above after the loops, and then the collected output from the loops after that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your HTML code like this:

```
<div>Total class: <span id="count">$count</span>
<div>Total student: <span>237</span>
```

and then create JavaScript code like this to set the value.

Edit: JavaScript code ***by PHP***

```
document.getElementById("count").innerHTML = variable;
```

Comment: You have to change the code, of course, it was an example only. I show you the way but do not do the complete work for you

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the variable first and the initialize later in php. For the same effect efficiently you can do something like.

```
<div>Total class: <span><?php echo count($row->newsSources); ?></span>
<div>Total student: <span>237</span>
//rest of the code
```

Comment: are there any requirement to keep the loop below the Total class: <span>$count</span>. The easiest way for you is to first run the loop and then print the $count. If you can provide the whole code then I can suggest you some alternative approach of what you are trying to do

Answer (score 0):

It is still not very clear what you are asking, but I think you want to render your html within the first loop, after the nested loop compleats. You can break the php code block after the nested loop `?> <?php` or use `echo`.

```
<?php
    foreach($cursor as $row) {
        $count = 0;
        foreach($row->class as $item) {
            $count+= count($row->class);
        }

        ?>
            <div>Total class: <span><?php echo $count; ?></span>
            <div>Total student: <span>237</span>
        <?php
    }
?>
```

Comment: I have to use it before for-each loop because there are other html value too that needs to print, any solution to use above loop and define later?